# 年利の計算について

Tags: c

実行例を次のようにしたいのですが、エラーが出てしまいます。

```
$ ./a.out
元金(円): 1000000
年利率(%): 0.001
預入期間(年): 10
 1年目: 1000010 円
 2年目: 1000020 円
 3年目: 1000030 円
 4年目: 1000040 円
 5年目: 1000050 円
 6年目: 1000060 円
 7年目: 1000070 円
 8年目: 1000080 円
 9年目: 1000090 円
10年目: 1000100 円
```

自分は次のようにプログラムしエラーが出てしまいました。

```
int main(void)
{
    int i,m,n,y;

    printf("元金： ");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    printf("年利率(%)： ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("預入期間(年)： ");
    scanf("%d",&y);
    for(i=m;i<=y;i=i+n/100){
        printf("i年目：%d円\n",i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
ex0304.c: In function ‘main’:
ex0304.c:8:24: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘)’ in format [-Wformat=]
     printf("年利率(%)： ");
                        ^
```

Answer (score 1):

`printf` 中や `scanf` 中のフォーマット文字列内において `%` は単独で使いません。必ず後ろに既知の一文字以上を伴う義務があります。一般文字列中の `\` と同じっすね。

百分率文字 `%` を画面に表示したいのなら `printf("%d%%", 100);` となります。

Answer (score 0):

`printf` では `%` 記号に続けて **型指定子** を記述する必要があります (以下の例なら "d" や "c" の部分)。

例:

```c
printf("%d", num); ## 10進数
printf("%s", str); ## 文字列
```

しかし、ワーニングの出ている箇所では `%` 記号そのままを出力しようと `(%)` のように記述していますが、ここで `%)` という未知の型指定をしたものとみなされてワーニングになっています。

`%` 記号を文字としてそのまま `printf` で出力したい場合には、`%%` のように記述します。

```c
printf("%d%%", num);
```

---

なお、ワーニングが表示されている箇所以外にも間違っている箇所が複数あるため、`printf` の部分だけを直しても期待通りの動作にはならないと思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。ご指摘いただいたとおり”%d%%"と直したのですが、やはり同じエラーが出てしまいました。できれば、自分が質問で示したプログラムに沿って教えてほしいです。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: @Acc さん、質問と回答が微妙にズレているように見えるのは、質問者さんが途中で質問自体を編集して内容を変えてしまったとか、あるいは初心者にそのものズバリの修正箇所だけ示すのは、そこで思考停止してしまうので良くないと考えて、今後も活用できそうな少し広い範囲の情報を示しているとか、そういったことが考えられます。覚えること/考えることが多くて大変だとは思いますが、もう少し余裕をもって焦らずに各回答の内容とコンパイラが表示している内容の関連がどんなものかを考えてみてください。

Comment: @Acc そもそも表示されているのはエラーではなく **ワーニング(警告)** です。エラーの場合はまず修正しないとプログラムが動きませんが、ワーニングの場合は動いてしまうケースがほとんどです (最終的にはどちらも直すべき)。 / 質問で提示されたコードのままでも、私の環境では `gcc -Wall` の様に明示的に警告フラグを付けてコンパイルしない限りワーニングも表示されません (CentOS7, gcc-4.8.5)。

Answer (score 0):

ちなみに、@cubick さんが「ワーニングが表示されている箇所以外にも間違っている箇所が複数ある」と言っているのは以下の点です。

- 年利率データは整数であらわせない値なのに、整数として変数に入力しようとしています。
  (ちなみにWindowsのVisualC++だと、実行しても年利率に`0.001`を入力すると次の預入期間(年):の入力がスキップされてしまい、かつ以下のように`for`ループは実行されず表示無しで終了します)
- `for`ループの制御部分でループ回数の制御と金利適用結果の計算が混ぜ合わされて意味のないものになっていて、かつ1度も実行されない状態になっています。
  (ループ回数の制御と金利適用結果の計算は独立して行いましょう)
- 例え実行できたとしても、結果表示に指定したフォーマット文字列および表示する変数の指定が間違っているので、希望する表示結果にはなりません。
  (表示するのにどんなデータが必要で、それはどうやってフォーマット文字列に組み込むかを考えてみてください)

少しだけ注意深くなって考えてみましょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます。もう少しじっくりと考えてみます。